# uncompress zip file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I used PowerShell for unzip files. It worked, but not anymore. I don't know why, it is the same code.

```powershell
$path = "C:\tmp\test.zip"
$date= Get-Date -DisplayHint Date -Format yyMMdd
$destination = "I:\"+$date+"\zk\"
$shell_app= New-Object -com shell.application
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -filter *.zip -recurse


foreach($file in $files) {
    $zip_file = $shell_app.namespace($file.FullName)
    $copyHere = $shell_app.namespace($destination)
    $copyHere.Copyhere($zip_file.items())
}
```

Error message:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:16 char:3
+   $copyHere.Copyhere($zip_file.items())
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: It looks like `$files` is not getting populated, therefore `$file` is empty in the loop. You have some odd looking quotes around `$path` and `$destination` values. They need to be standard `"` quotes. That could be preventing the command from finding the zip files

Comment: Looks like it could be an empty ZIP file; perhaps check if there's any files to extract before calling a copy method on them?

Comment: `$destination` had some odd quoting that might just have been copy/paste error. I updated the quotes.

Comment: Thanks, it s working... :)